# Check completion of async task from a different thread

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, mvvm, task

I'm using async tasks to upload files and update the database. I need to know when the application is closed to update the upload status in the DB.

My task is in a ViewModel class.

```
private async void OnUpload(object param)
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            ...
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

What should I put in my MainWindow OnClosing Event?

```
protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    ....

    base.OnClosing(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a bool variable `IsTaskCompleted` in your class and keep default value to `false`. As a last statement in the `try` block of your task, set `IsTaskCompleted` to `true`.

Check this variable in the closing event handler, if value is `false` that means task isn't got completed.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd publish an event from the `OnClosing` using Reactive Extensions (RX) and a `Subject`.

Everywhere in the program that I need it, I'd subscribe to the event and perform any cleanup.

This would decouple the `OnClosing` event from all of the subscribers that do the cleanup, and would let you place the cleanup code for the database and the heavy lifting code for the database close to each other.